# Cannot invoke StrFormatByteSize64 in WinXP?

Tags: windows, delphi, dll

I am using the function StrFormatByteSize64 in Delphi XE3 based on the post at [Delphi Function to Display Number of Bytes as Windows Does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285979/delphi-function-to-display-number-of-bytes-as-windows-does) .

However, when starting my app in Windows XP, I get error "cannot find entry point StrFormatByteSize64W 
 in shlwapi.dll". However, I check the document of StrFormatByteSize64  at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strformatbytesize64a and it said the function supports Windows XP and higher versions.

Why it does not work for WinXP?

Thanks

**Update**

What I try to call is just StrFormatByteSize64 in my codes. However, it seems that Delphi redirect the call to StrFormatByteSize64W. I have to change StrFormatByteSize64 to StrFormatByteSizeW in my code to solve the problem.

Comment: Enitely possible that it was implemented in a different way in earlier versions. Perhaps inline in the header file. Consult the header files to see what is actually going on.

Comment: Or just give up and fallback on something hand coded for XP. After all, XP is long out of support, even Vista and 7 are also out of support now.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your quoted error message you have called `StrFormatByteSize64W`. But if you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strformatbytesize64a?redirectedfrom=MSDN) it says (emphasis mine):

> Remarks
>
> StrFormatByteSize64 can be used for either ANSI or Unicode characters. However, while StrFormatByteSize64A can be called directly, **StrFormatByteSize64W is not defined**. When StrFormatByteSize64 is called with a Unicode value, StrFormatByteSizeW is used.

So, call `StrFormatByteSize64()`

Comment: Thank you. What I try to call is just StrFormatByteSize64 in my codes. However, it seems that Delphi redirect the call to StrFormatByteSize64W. I have to change StrFormatByteSize64 to StrFormatByteSizeW in my code to solve the problem.